# How can I call this method using a button?

Tags: c#-4.0

```
    public static bool WriteBeamDataToFile(string Filename, List<Part> Parts)
        {
            // Open a Streamwriter to write data to the specified Filename
            using (StreamWriter TeklaDataWriter = new StreamWriter(Filename))
            {
                // Connect to the Currently Open Tekla Model
                Model Model = new Model();
                foreach (Part CurrentPart in Parts)
                {
                    if (CurrentPart != null)
                    {
                        string Name = CurrentPart.Name;
                        string Profile = CurrentPart.Profile.ProfileString;
                        string Material = CurrentPart.Material.MaterialString;
                        string Finish = CurrentPart.Finish;

                        TeklaDataWriter.WriteLine(Name + "," + Profile + "," + Material + "," + Finish);
                    }

                }
            }

            return File.Exists(Filename);
        }
```

Example:

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        How to call above method here?
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    private bool isFileExists;
    List<Parts> partsList = new List<Parts>();
    isFileExists = WriteBeamDataToFile("example.txt",partsList)

    if(isFileExists){
       //do something..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Method above is mark as static. That's why you faced some issue.
Static method could be call from Class it' self.
While non static methods could be called from class instance.

See example:

```
class MyClass { 
  //static method
  public static void Method1() {}
  //non static method
  public void Method2() {}
}

class MyForm:Form { 
 ...
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      //here we call static method of MyClass
      MyClass.Method1(); 
    }
//or
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     // Here we create an instance of MyClass
     var class = new MyClass(); 
     // and call non static Method
     class.Method2(); 
    }
  }
}
```